# texture paint is making unwanted duplication

Tags: texture-painting

Texture paint is mirroring onto another part of my model. Any one know how to stop this? I've tried masking with selected faces and UV unwrapping with no success.

Comment: Can you add an image of what is happening including your interface so we can see and give a better idea of what might be going on? Possibilities could include improper assumptions concerning UV mapping, Object Origin off from center of mass affecting Mirror symmetry, or even just X, Y or Z axis symmetry on when unexpected.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the replies, it was the UV mapping. I projected from view. Once I'd put in some UV seams and re-mapped the mirroring stopped.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have flipped normals, go in *Edit* mode, select all and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> > *Recalculate Normals*